# Comparing a list to a dataframe column and create new column with numbers

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, series

I have a dataframe where one column contains urls. I want to compare it to a list of string values and wherever they match add a number to a new column.

The column looks something like this:

```
source
www.fox5.com/some_article
www.nyt.com/some_article
www.fox40news.com/some_article
www.cnn.com/another_article
...
```

I want to compare it to this list:

```
sources = ['fox', 'yahoo', 'abcnews', 'google', 'cnn', 'nyt', 'nbc', 
'washingtonpost', 'wsj', 'huffingtonpost']
```

and where the sources value is contained in the source column add the corresponding number of the list location to a new column. So the resulting new column would look something like this:

```
    sources                       sourcenum
www.fox5.com/some_article         1
www.nyt.com/some_article          6
www.fox40news.com/some_article    1
www.cnn.com/another_article       5
...                               ...
```

Ive tried using a for loop with a count:

```
count = 1
for x in sources:
    if x in df.source.values:
        df.sourcenum = count
    count += 1
```

but the output is just all 0's

I also tried using numpys where but that doesnt accept 10 arguments.

The list could be changed to a dictionary like so if that would work better

```
sources = {'fox':1, 'yahoo':2, 'abcnews':3, 'google':4, 'cnn':5, 'nyt':6, 
       'nbc':7, 'washingtonpost':8, 'wsj':9, 'huffingtonpost':10}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a generator expression with `enumerate`. In the below implementation we cycle through an enumerated `sources` list. `next` extracts the first instance of a partial match. If no partial match exists, `0` is returned.

```
sources = ['fox', 'yahoo', 'abcnews', 'google', 'cnn', 'nyt', 'nbc', 
           'washingtonpost', 'wsj', 'huffingtonpost']

def sourcer(x):
    return next((i for i, j in enumerate(sources, 1) if j in x), 0)

df['sourcenum'] = df['source'].apply(sourcer)

print(df)

                           source  sourcenum
0       www.fox5.com/some_article          1
1        www.nyt.com/some_article          6
2  www.fox40news.com/some_article          1
3     www.cnn.com/another_article          5
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like regular expression can help resolve the problem. Python has 're' module, though I'm not the expert of Python.

But the idea is compose a 'pattern' with your sources list, and match that pattern against the strings. I believe you could get the count of matches which is the number you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `tldextract` package to get domain name of the url.

Then, apply `get_close_matches` function from 
`difflib` package to get closest string.

And finally use `.index` to get corresponding index number from list of sources:

```
import tldextract
from difflib import get_close_matches
df['sourcenum'] = df['source'].apply(lambda row:sources.index(
                                get_close_matches(
                                tldextract.extract(row).domain, sources, cutoff=.5)[0])+1)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
                           source  sourcenum
0       www.fox5.com/some_article          1
1        www.nyt.com/some_article          6
2  www.fox40news.com/some_article          1
3     www.cnn.com/another_article          5
```

**Note:** in code above, for function `get_close_matches` the value for `cutoff=.5` was set otherwise close match for `fox40news` was not found.